# Java for-loop not iterating, stops the method after one iteration rather than repeating

Tags: java, for-loop

I am working on a homework assignment where I must fill an array and check to see if there are four consecutive numbers anywhere in it being up and down, side to side, or diagonal. I think i have the logic down but my for loop is stopping at the first iteration instead of searching through the array. Any help is appreciated.

```
public static boolean isConsecutiveFour(int[][] values) {
    int One = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            One = values[i][j];
            //System.out.println(One);
            // up and down
            if (values[i + 1][j] == One) {
                if (values[i + 2][j] == One) {
                    if (values[i + 3][j] == One) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            // left to right
            if (values[i][j + 1] == One) {
                if (values[i][j + 2] == One) {
                    if (values[i][j + 3] == One) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            // diagonal to right
            if (values[i + 1][j + 1] == One) {
                if (values[i + 2][j + 2] == One) {
                    if (values[i + 3][j + 3] == One) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            // diagonal to left
            if (i >= 3 && j >=3) {
                if (values[i - 1][j - 1] == One) {
                    if (values[i - 2][j - 2] == One) {
                        if (values[i - 3][j - 3] == One) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else
                return false;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Please provide the `values` array.

Comment: `int One = 0;` whät?

Comment: You've posted a large amount of code here - please reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: But I suspect the `else return false;` may well be the problem here...

Comment: What's with that `else return false` after the last `if`? Seems not to make much sense

Comment: Indeed - it means that the first iteration will *always* return. `i` and `j` will both be 0, so if none of the earlier statements has returned anything, this will always return false.

Answer (score 5):

```
// diagonal to left
if (i >= 3 && j >=3) {
    if (values[i - 1][j - 1] == One) {
        if (values[i - 2][j - 2] == One) {
            if (values[i - 3][j - 3] == One) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
} else
    return false;
```

The problem is if this last `if` statement fails, the `else` clause triggers and returns `false`. It is premature to return here just because one particular check has failed.

Get rid of the `else` clause. You don't want to return `false` until all of the loop iterations have run. The final `return false` at the end of the function is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

I did not check your whole code, but your for-conditions seems wrong to me. Typically you check in the outer for-loop for the first dimension of an array and in the inner for the second dimension. Also you should use values[i].length in the inner loop, because it is possible, that the length of values[1] is lower then the length of value[0].

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
```